# Selecionar apenas 1ª linha da tabela

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso selecionar somente a linha 1 da tabela, já usei o `DISTINCT` e não funcionou

segue a Query:

```
select

 Max(remessa.dt_uso_inicio) as DATA_REMESSA
,min(dt_entorc_oficina)DATA_ABERTURA
,patr.nr_patrimonio AS PATRIMONIO

from 

orcos as o 
join 
patrimon as patr
on o.cd_PATRIMONIO= patr.cd_PATRIMONIO
join
v_remessa_patrimonio as remessa
on remessa.cd_patrimonio = patr.cd_patrimonio 

where patr.nr_patrimonio = '070-13 GEA'
group by
patr.nr_patrimonio
,o.dt_entorc_oficina
having o.dt_entorc_oficina > max(remessa.dt_uso_inicio)

;
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Tópico de continuação: 
[Selecionar a linha com a data mais antiga dentro dessa query entre os valores repetidos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/192196/selecionar-a-linha-com-a-data-mais-antiga-dentro-dessa-query-entre-os-valores-re)

Comment: A cláusula SELECT TOP é usado para especificar o número de registros a serem retornados. SQL Server / MS Access Sintaxe: SELECT TOP number|percent .....

Answer (score 2):

Use [TOP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms189463.aspx)(1).

```
 SELECT TOP(1) Max(remessa.dt_uso_inicio) AS DATA_REMESSA,
       min(dt_entorc_oficina)DATA_ABERTURA,
       patr.nr_patrimonio AS PATRIMONIO
FROM orcos AS o
JOIN patrimon AS patr ON o.cd_PATRIMONIO= patr.cd_PATRIMONIO
JOIN v_remessa_patrimonio AS remessa ON remessa.cd_patrimonio = patr.cd_patrimonio
WHERE patr.nr_patrimonio = '070-13 GEA'
GROUP BY patr.nr_patrimonio,
         o.dt_entorc_oficina
HAVING o.dt_entorc_oficina > max(remessa.dt_uso_inicio);
```

Comment: Olá @jbueno, valeu mas na tabela onde tenho outros dados ele só pegou o primeiro, na verdade preciso pegar só o dado mais antigo entre os repetidos. vou postar a query completa pra vc ver. abraço!

Comment: Não conhecia essa construção com parênteses.

Comment: Acho que os parênteses são irrelevantes, @CiganoMorrisonMendez

Answer (score 0):

> (...) *preciso pegar só o dado mais antigo entre os repetidos.*

Jander, considerando-se o código que postou no início deste tópico, me parece que somente a cláusula GROUP BY é que necessita ser reescrita. Se para cada valor do par (DATA_REMESSA, PATRIMONIO) deve-se retornar somente a linha com o menor valor para DATA_ABERTURA, então o código ficaria assim:

```
-- código #1
SELECT DATA_REMESSA= remessa.dt_uso_inicio,
       DATA_ABERTURA= min(o.dt_entorc_oficina),
       PATRIMONIO= patr.nr_patrimonio
  from orcos as o 
       inner join patrimon as patr on o.cd_PATRIMONIO = patr.cd_PATRIMONIO
       inner join v_remessa_patrimonio as remessa on remessa.cd_patrimonio = patr.cd_patrimonio 
  --where patr.nr_patrimonio = '070-13 GEA'
  group by patr.nr_patrimonio, remessa.dt_uso_inicio;
```

A impressão inicial que tenho é que a cláusula HAVING não é necessária; avalie localmente.

Answer (score 0):

veja se assim da certo...

```
SELECT TOP 1

 MAX(remessa.dt_uso_inicio) DATA_REMESSA
,MIN(dt_entorc_oficina) DATA_ABERTURA
,patr.nr_patrimonio PATRIMONIO

FROM

orcos o 
JOIN 
 patrimon patr
 ON o.cd_PATRIMONIO= patr.cd_PATRIMONIO
JOIN
 v_remessa_patrimonio remessa
 ON remessa.cd_patrimonio = patr.cd_patrimonio 

WHERE patr.nr_patrimonio = '070-13 GEA'
GROUP BY
 patr.nr_patrimonio
 ,o.dt_entorc_oficina
 having o.dt_entorc_oficina > max(remessa.dt_uso_inicio)
ORDER BY DATA_REMESSA DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Acho que existe um erro conceitual na sua query.

O campo dt_entorc_oficina está no gtoup by e no min() ao mesmo tempo, o que é muito estranho.

Supondo que você colocou o min() para tentar trazer uma única query, sugiro que você tire este min() e faça como os colegas acima disseram, que é usar select top 1.

Boa sorte!