# Selecionar a linha com a data mais antiga dentro dessa query entre os valores repetidos

Tags: sql-server, tabela-banco-de-dados

```
select e.nm_equipto as EQUIPAMENTOS
    ,Max(remessa.dt_uso_inicio) as DATA_REMESSA --,(SELECT MAX(DT_ENTORC_OFICINA) FROM ORCOS)as DATA_ABERTURA 
    ,MIN(dt_entorc_oficina) as DATA_ABERTURA 
    ,o.numero as NÚMERO 
    ,patr.nr_patrimonio as PATRIMÔNIO 
    ,DATEDIFF ( DAY , MAX(remessa.dt_uso_inicio), o.dt_entorc_oficina)as QTD_DIAS
from orcos as o
inner join equipto as e on o.cd_equipto = e.cd_equipto
inner join patrimon as patr on o.cd_patrimonio = patr.cd_patrimonio
inner join est_almox as almox on almox.cd_almox = patr.cd_almox
inner join v_remessa_patrimonio as remessa on remessa.cd_patrimonio = patr.cd_patrimonio
group by o.numero
    ,patr.nr_patrimonio
    ,o.dt_entorc_oficina
    ,patr.cd_almox
    ,e.nm_equipto
having o.dt_entorc_oficina > max(remessa.dt_uso_inicio)
    and count(o.numero) > 1
    and patr.cd_almox = '6'
order by o.numero desc
```

[![O dados estão nessa tabela
1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HIakS.png)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: a menor data na coluna DATA_ABERTURA

Comment: Por favor, não fique postando perguntas duplicadas. **Isso não vai te ajudar** a ter uma resposta mais rápido. Ao invés de ficar floodando o site, tente ser mais claro na sua explicação e adicionar detalhes na pergunta existente. Link da duplicada: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/192170/18246

Comment: @JanderHelius: Poderia acrescentar acima (na descrição do problema) informações adicionais para facilitar a compreensão do problema bem como auxiliar na postagem de sugestões? Por exemplo, qual é o objetivo da consulta, o que contém cada tabela envolvida etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considerando-se o código completo que postou neste tópico, eis outra sugestão:

```
-- código #2 v5
with tbOPR as (
SELECT r.dt_uso_inicio as DATA_REMESSA,
       o.dt_entorc_oficina as DATA_ABERTURA,
       o.numero as NÚMERO,
       o.cd_equipto,
       p.nr_patrimonio as PATRIMÔNIO, 
       p.cd_almox,
       Seq= row_number() over (partition by p.nr_patrimonio,
                                            r.dt_uso_inicio
                               order by o.dt_entorc_oficina asc)
  from orcos as o
       inner join patrimon as p on o.cd_patrimonio = p.cd_patrimonio
       inner join v_remessa_patrimonio as r on r.cd_patrimonio = p.cd_patrimonio
  where r.dt_uso_inicio < o.dt_entorc_oficina
        and p.cd_almox = '6'
)
SELECT OPR.cd_almox,
       e.nm_equipto as EQUIPAMENTOS,
       OPR.DATA_REMESSA, OPR.DATA_ABERTURA, OPR.NÚMERO, OPR.PATRIMÔNIO,
       QTD_DIAS= DateDiff(day, OPR.DATA_REMESSA, OPR.DATA_ABERTURA)
  from tbOPR as OPR
       inner join equipto as e on OPR.cd_equipto = e.cd_equipto
  where OPR.Seq = 1;
```

Comment: @JoséDias testei aqui e mesmo assim persiste a duplicidade e a DATA_REMESSA tem que ser menor que a DATA_ABERTURA e no caso onde está: WHERE P.CD_ALMOX = '6' é pra pegar só alguns tipos de equipamentos e está pegando até mesmo os que não pertencem a este almoxarifado. já tentei várias formas e continua persistente a duplicidade. Muito Obrigado!

Comment: @JanderHelius: a respeito de "a DATA_REMESSA tem que ser menor que a DATA_ABERTURA", acrescentei essa restrição na cláusula WHERE da CTE tbOPR. // Já sobre "P.CD_ALMOX = '6' é pra pegar só alguns tipos de equipamentos e está pegando até mesmo os que não pertencem a este almoxarifado", para verificação acrescentei a coluna p.cd_almox na exibição do resultado final. Como está declarada a coluna p.cd_almox? // Para ter retorno da sugestão proposta, por favor teste o código #2 v5 como está, sem modificá-lo.

Comment: @JanderHelius: caso persistam as duplicidades, verifique na definição do banco de dados como são as junções entre tabelas. Talvez esteja faltando algo na cláusula FROM.

Comment: consegui fazer. Muito obrigado pelo auxilio. Grande Abraço!